# Function for the evaluation of a Random Forest learning, through cross validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm just learning to program in Python and would like to know if what I wrote is right: my task is to write a function `RandomForestCV(folds,XTrain,YTrain,XTest,YTest,n_estimators,randomization,bootstrap)` in Python, that evaluates the "n_estimators, randomization, bootstrap" configuration in a Random Forest learning using the fscore metric; my function should return the average fscore computed via cross-validation.

I've developed the following function:

```
def RandomForestCV(folds,XTrain,YTrain,XTest,YTest,n_estimators,randomization,bootstrap):
    for i in range(folds):
        clf = randomforest(XTrain[i], YTrain[i], n_estimators, randomization, bootstrap)
        scores = cross_validate(clf, XTest[i], YTest[i], scoring="f1", cv=folds)

    return scores['test_score'].mean()
```

XTrain, YTrain, XTest, YTest are lists of Dataframes, resulting from a cross validation carried out previously (e.g. 5-fold CV, so I will have XTrain which will be a list of 5 Dataframes, etc, which I can access through an index). For the evaluation I used the sklearn [cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate) library.

I don't think it's correct because at each iteration I think I overwrite every time the variable `scores`, so at the end I will get only the average f_score regarding the last fold of the list (but I'm not sure), how can I fix it? Or should I do it all over again?

Comment: what you really want is to wrap the straight line of codes into a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly apply `cross_validate` on your complete dataset, this function takes care of splitting your data internally.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, Y = make_classification(n_features=2,
                           n_redundant=0,
                           n_informative=2,
                           random_state=1,
                           n_clusters_per_class=1)


n_estimators = 10
folds =  5
bootstrap = True

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators, bootstrap=bootstrap)
scores = cross_validate(clf, X, Y, scoring='f1', cv=folds, return_train_score=True)

print(f'Average F1-score training: {scores["train_score"].mean()}')
print(f'Std F1-score training: {scores["train_score"].std()}')
print(f'Average F1-score test: {scores["train_score"].mean()}')
print(f'Std F1-score test: {scores["train_score"].std()}')
```

Comment: So it's wrong by me to use cross_validate if I already have the split dataset, isn't it? But I have to respect the function according to the passed parameters, so how can I modify the function? 

Would I get the same result if I wrote a for? In which I would train the random forest with XTrain and YTrain, and then evaluate the clf with XTest and YTest with f1_score, for each fold? At the end of the cycle I sum all the f1_score for each fold and divide by the number of folds, and get the average, right?

Comment: In your code, you first fit the model and then use `cross_validate`, but the trained model will be overwritten inside that function. `cross_validate` takes care of splitting the data, fitting it on the training split and evaluating your model on the test split. If you only want to get the f1_scores you can also use `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`.

Comment: You've been very clear about ```cross_validate```; so the solution is to find another way. So, is it enough to replace cross_validate with ```cross_val_score``` in my code? However, the ```scores``` variable needs to be instantiated outside of the for loop, right? Otherwise, at each iteration it's instantiated again and again (so, if yes, I've to write ```scores[i]``` in the loop). So, can I ask you to take my code and modify it appropriately? Would it be correct then to replace cross_validate like this? ```scores[i] = cross_val_score(clf, XTest[i], YTest[i], scoring="f1", cv=folds)```

Comment: I've read the library, ```cross_val_score``` also performs cross validation, so I don't think it's the correct solution, because my data have already done cross validation, so it would perform an additional one, internally. Similar to ```cross_validate```, but only a single metric is permitted. So, the solution could be: after getting the random forest
```y_predict = clf.predict(YTest[i])```
```scores[i]= f1_score(YTest[i], y_predict)```
and then, outside the for
```return scores[].mean()```

semantically, can it work?